# jgrowl on iis5

Tags: jgrowl

for some reason jGrowl does not want to work on my IIS 5 (live) server, but works perfectly on my IIS 6 (staging) server. has anyone else experienced this problem or is it just my setup?

on iis5 i'm getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: on iis5 i'm getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: <apology-if-i-sound-like-a-smart-ass/>

This would be one reason to convince your organization to provide resources to ensure that you can have a staging server that matches as closely as reasonably possible to your production server, so you can work these things out in staging rather than in production.

If you have a spare PC and dev licenses for OS, setup an IIS5 environment in which to debug.

Comment: the migration is in process, but it takes time to get rid of legacy code, so for now all code must run in both environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jGrowl (and jQuery) don't run on the servers, they run on the clients. Because of that, I'm thinking your problem is elsewhere. You could back up, and try the following code to be sure jQuery and jGrowl are functioning properly.

```
$(function(){
  $.jGrowl("I work!");
});
```

Also, if you could post a simple example of how you're using jQuery + jGrowl, that would help diagnose the issue as well.

What browsers have you tested this in? Are you **absolutely** positive you are referencing the plugin-source in your page? Try copying/pasting the reference source from your code directly into your url.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, I would like to further suggest that you also look at things that are "different" between the 2 environments.  It could be that there is a DLL not registered/installed on the production server that is running/installed on the staging server.

Comment: ok tested your code, strangely jquery works fine, but jgrowl does not, weird.

Comment: i'm convinced that it must be a server issue, irrespective of which browser i get the same result - all works on staging - jgrowl js does not on live

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.jGrowl('this is a test', { 
header: 'Good Morning',
position: 'bottom-right',
theme:'smoke',          
sticky: false
});" >

Comment: Daniel, are you sure the source for your jGrowl plugin is properly referenced in the file?

Comment: Daniel, is your page public-facing? Can we view it?

Comment: its not a public facing page, sorry.

i just created this test page, again it works locally and on staging, but not on live:

Comment: <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Scripts/jQuery/plugin/jGrowl-1.2.0/jquery.jgrowl.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jQuery/plugin/jGrowl-1.2.0/jquery.jgrowl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.jGrowl('hello world');">test</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: SOLVED!!!!! :)

OK, Jonathan was right, it is the referencing that does not work on live, although the file and folder structure is 100% the same on live and staging. I copy pasted the jgrowl js directly into my test page and all worked fine. I don't know why the reference does not want to work on live, but at least it works now. I'm going to move all the js to a top folder in the wwwroot, I hope a simpler central location will help, and reference it there.

Thank you Jonathan & James for your assistance.
Cheers
Daniel